# ASP.NET Maintain Scroll position o Post Back in Ever Updating Firefox Chrome

Tags: asp.net

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx)

Maintaining scroll position works in IE and used to work in Firefox (before we jumped from 3.6 to 9.something).   Has anyone had any success getting this to work in Firefox or Chrome ??

Comment: Are you using an updatePanel or master pages? And this problem occurs on postback correct?

Comment: @justinlabenne yes I am using master pages, why is there a work around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this javascript. You have to put hiddenfield where you want to set scroll after postback.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var scroll = {
        Y: '#<%= hfScrollPosition.ClientID %>'
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#scrollable-container").scrollTop($(scroll.Y).val());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a guess here: 
http://gnidesign.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-maintain-page-scroll-on-postback.html

Comment: good call I was only using the declaration not that little javascript tag, however after adding it it doesn't seem to make a difference.  Must be a another way to do it.

Comment: Used the page directive, owrked liek a charm, thank you for sharing !